# Javascript event to fire after all script files have been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website is image intensive which means images take up a huge amount of my page load time.
I am using the google maps API which works better if run on a `window load` event, however given that window load waits for all images to load first, the user experience on the map is affected negatively to an extent.

This can be remedied if I can get a separate event that targets just the completion of loading for the script files and begins rendering the map without concerning itself about the status of the images.

Now I know this is a weird thing to do, but given the scenario I have explained, any insights or workarounds over this will be helpful.

PS : Since I am loading my maps with the cluster module, I have no other option but to wait for all the scripts to load first, hence `document ready` is not an option. Also loading scripts before the map initiation js doesn't work since the map clustering always occurs with a delay loading external javascript and hence I have to rely on `window load`.

Comment: Maybe you should concatenate/minify all your javascript and at the end of the very end initiate the google map.

Comment: It all depends on the layout, but you can try lazy loading the images.  Or even leave the src empty and set a data property with the src.  Then on load you can set all the image src's to their corresponding data properties.  That way the window load event will fire before the images are downloaded.  And all the images will load along with the map instead of before

Comment: @Smeegs - yes, I am doing my lazy loading for content outside the window,need to show the images on the window during page load for SEO purposes.

Comment: Made an edit to my question further clarifying the point I was trying to make, which is what renders any solutions provided unusable.

Answer (score 6):

This I found works form me:

```
var everythingLoaded = setInterval(function() {
  if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
    clearInterval(everythingLoaded);
    init(); // this is the function that gets called when everything is loaded
  }
}, 10);
```

reference: http://callmenick.com/post/check-if-everything-loaded-with-javascript

Comment: Does this wait for async flag on script tags?

Comment: @chovy If the scripts are done by the time the dom is ready, sure. but that's not guarenteed (and is probably unlikely)

Answer (score 2):

okay there is a way to do this, but you may not like it because it only works in modern browsers.

In HTML5 script elements have a property called async. If you set this to false with Javascript, scripts are added and run in the order they are presented in your page code.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = src;
script.async = false;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

[link to reference](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Comment: this is interesting +1, doesn't solve my purpose though

Answer (score 1):

DOMReady is about as close as you can get.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //run the code here
});
```

Unfortunately, if the scripts you are loading further load more scripts, you can't really detect that other than watching for specific properties of the window to become available using a setInterval.

Comment: This is exactly my problem wherein the main map js loads external modules for clusters - this is one event that could be really helpful making web pages faster. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

DOMReady is about as close as you'll get, though (if you aren't) you should be following "scripts last" rule of thumb.

```
<body>
  <!-- Content -->

  <!--
    Other JavaScript Files
  -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initializeMap"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initializeMap(){ // as specified with callback= above
      var map = new google.maps.Map(...),
          ...;
      // etc.
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

With that said, if images are the bottleneck, you may want to look in to [lazy-loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) them using some kind of plugin (jquery one referenced). this keeps bandwidth low, load time fast, and content remains "on-demand" (if they scroll down they'll get the additional content, otherwise it's never loaded).

Comment: I have lazy loading working, however when it comes to loading maps with clusterers, domready is not an option and even with javascript for map initiation after the script files, the cluster object is never fully loaded, hence I have no option other that ensuring all the js is loaded using window load.